# Facing issue while calling @ReactMethod from ReactNative app to standalone Android App

Tags: android, react-native

I have a ReactNative App, which I have generated bundle file and integrated in a standalone Android app.
The Android app uses ReactRootView as per documentation to invoke the attached Bundle file and loads my reactNative app on Android app.

Now I need to pass data from ReactNative app to Android app(Kotlin). I tried implementing but while accessing the NativeModule in ReactNativeApp I get Nativemodule = {}.

Here is my below code files:
**MainApplication.kt**

```
class MainApplication : Application(), ReactApplication {
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false)
}

private val mReactNativeHost: ReactNativeHost = object : ReactNativeHost(this) {
    override fun getUseDeveloperSupport(): Boolean {
        return BuildConfig.DEBUG
    }

    override fun getPackages(): List<ReactPackage>? {
        return listOf(
            MainReactPackage(),
            MyKotlinModulePackage()
        )
    }

    override fun getJSMainModuleName(): String {
        return "index"
    }
}

override fun getReactNativeHost(): ReactNativeHost {
    return mReactNativeHost
}}
```

**MyKotlinModule.kt**

```
class MyKotlinModule(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext) : ReactContextBaseJavaModule(reactContext) {
override fun getName(): String {
    return "MyKotlinModule"
}

@ReactMethod
fun sendData(data: String) {
    // Handle the received data here
    // You can call other functions in your Kotlin app
    // and pass the data to them
}
```

}

**MyKotlinModulePackage.kt**

```
class MyKotlinModulePackage : ReactPackage {
override fun createNativeModules(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): List<NativeModule> {
    val modules = mutableListOf<NativeModule>()
    modules.add(MyKotlinModule(reactContext)) // Add your MyKotlinModule here
    return modules
}

override fun createViewManagers(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): List<ViewManager<*, *>> {
    return emptyList()
}}
```

**MyReactActivity**

```
class MyReactActivity: AppCompatActivity(), DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler{

private lateinit var reactRootView: ReactRootView
private lateinit var reactInstanceManager: ReactInstanceManager

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    SoLoader.init(this, true)

    reactRootView = ReactRootView(this)

    reactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
        .setApplication(application)
        .setCurrentActivity(this)
        .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
        .setJSMainModulePath("index")
        .addPackage(MainReactPackage()) // Add required packages
        .addPackage(MyKotlinModulePackage()) // Add required packages
        .setJavaScriptExecutorFactory(HermesExecutorFactory()) // Added to fix java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor
        .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
        .build()

    val initialProperties = Bundle().apply {
        putString("Test","ABC")
    }

    reactRootView.startReactApplication(reactInstanceManager, "HelloProject", initialProperties)
    setContentView(reactRootView)

}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    reactInstanceManager.onHostPause(this)
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    reactInstanceManager.onHostResume(this, this)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    reactInstanceManager.onHostDestroy(this)
    reactRootView.unmountReactApplication()
}


override fun invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
    reactInstanceManager.onBackPressed()
    super.onBackPressed()
}}
```

**In ReactNative Project:**

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const App = (props)=>{
  console.log(NativeModules) // Returns = {}
}
```

In my ReactNative Project when I access NativeModules I am expecting **MyKotlinModule** to be present but getting **{}**

Can you please help where am I going wrong